# What is the "best" way to make a diy 7v rechargeable battery?

Tags: batteries, buck, diy, step-down, step-up

I have a device (the wii "sensor" bar, basically an IR LED array) that the literature says takes 7v. I can't find any battery offerings that come in 7v, but many that are 3.7v, so I am stuck trying to find some other solution.

Optimally, I want to create a rechargeable battery pack that is cheap and can give me those 7v, while also being small and practical (no 4x AAA for example).

I am considering three different options.

I have a 12v A23 cell, so perhaps a rechargeable A23 cell stepped down to 7v. But I have little knowledge and no experience with step down converters.

Another option is to connect two 3.7v batteries in series, but I read in a comment that this would require a balancer, because otherwise one of the cells might, uh, burst when charging. I had not heard about a balancer before, but I have an old laptop battery with 18650 cells that I had taken apart and it seems to contain a component that looks like that's what its purpose was.

The last option is to use a 5v source (like a small power bank) with a step up converter. But again, little knowledge and no experience on the matter.

So how should I go about it? I have lipo charger boards (I think they are TP4056) that I got some years ago and could probably use for this, and a cheap dollar store powerbank that uses an 18650 cell with usb connectors (but it gets really hot).

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use a single lithium ion battery and a step up voltage converter.

Comment: @user1850479  a single cell, not a battery

Comment: Would voltage matter when it comes to the cell to be used?

Comment: Post a link to that Led array. Maybe a current drive (not voltage) is a better option.

Comment: FWIW, Google turns up people saying you can power the 7V sensor bar with an ordinary 9V battery.  Pictures show a series resistor, so I suppose it just gets slightly brighter. A step up converter (or just changing the resistor) is definitely cleaner though.

Comment: Would running it at 9v not decrease the lifespan of the LEDs?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický http://jondontdoit.blogspot.com/2012/08/wii-sensor-bar-repair.html

Comment: 9V rechargeable battery has 250mAh capacity. Considering 25mA led current you can expect about 10hours lasting. Is that enough for you? You can build a simple one transistor current limiter if you worry about overdriving.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I'm not too worried about how long the battery charge lasts, rather in the simplicity and size of the device, and of course that it won't go catching fire or burning out the LEDs in the sensor bar. Do you have a link for the transistor current limiter circuit you are proposing?

Comment: I'm going to purchase some MT3608,  TP4056 (USB-C connector), and  LM2596S modules and test with these. Anything I should be looking out for?

Answer (score 0):

Simple current limitter bellow:

This do the job much effectively then simple resistor limitter on Wii board.
A Led current fluctuates much less over battery voltage change.

You have to remove/short the 74ohm resistor on Wii board since the current limitting do the transistor.

This limitter holds a constant current in all battery range (8-10V) in about 10% precision.

The Led current is set by Rx according formula on papper.
(For 20mA led current try Rx=33ohm)

[image]

Comment: Hi Michal, thank you for the answer! I might have to do some reading to understand everything you've written there, but I did want to ask, when you say "wii board" do you mean the pcb of the sensor bar? What I am hoping to do is not open the sensor itself, rather just create a small attachment, about the size of a small battery, and connect that to the sensor.

Comment: If you don’t want to open the sensor to remove the resistor rather use 9V battery +  7 or 8V LDO (low dropout regulator).